# Footer not showing the way I would like to

Tags: php, html, css

So, I've been trying for some time now to figure out how to position a footer correctly. I was browsing some already-asked questions here on SO and I found some ideas which I implemented but that didn't make my footer to work.

Here is the basic explanation. I have bellow written code for my footer. The problem is that the footer "fly" in page if post is not long. I'm coding (better say rewritting) a simple CMS from C to PHP and I'm not into CSS or design overall.

Here is the code:

```
#footer {
       position: static;
       background: #346 repeat scroll 0 0;
       border-top:3px solid #CCCCCC;
       clear: both;
       color:#FFFFFF;
       font-size:x-small;
       line-height:100%;
       margin: 2em 0 0;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       padding:3px 10px 10px;
       bottom: 0;
}
```

Single post view (bad, you see white space left bellow the footer):
[image: single post]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/836/0399596165.png))</sub>

Few posts that filled whole page (good, footer bellow pagination):
[image: full view]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/836/4115186425.png))</sub>

On the other side when I have position set to fixed I have this overflow:
[image: Bug]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/836/1684455056.png))</sub>

How do I make my code works fine like in picture where it says (good)?

EDIT: For those who say to change position, I've already tried all positions property (static, absolute, fixed, relative, inherit).

Here is my container code:

```
#contener {
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: left;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Other:

```
body, html, #menu, img, a img, form, fieldset {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

---

When I set position to "absolute" I got this [picture](https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/836/1657180315.png).

Here is my full code of pagination + footer:

```
<?php
    $currentPage = 1;               
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $currentPage = protect_sqli($_GET['page']); 
    }       

    $e = $currentPage * $num_psts;                                  // end post
    $p = $e - $num_psts+1;                                          // start post
    $i = 0;                                                             

    // Create a connection
    $conS =     mysqli_connect($hName, $dbUser) or die(mysql_error());

    // Select a specific database
                mysqli_select_db($conS, $dbName) or die(mysql_error());

    // Query creating
    $result = mysqli_query($conS, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY dat DESC, tim DESC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $i++;
        if($i >= $p && $i <= $e)
        {
            $postId = protect_sqli($row['slug']);
            readfile('p/' . $postId . '.php');
        }
    }

?>

<center>
    <p>
    <?php 
        $result     = mysqli_query($conS, "SELECT id FROM posts");
        $nPosts     = mysqli_num_rows($result);                     // number of posts

        mysqli_close($conS);

        echo "Pages: ";

        $pages = $nPosts/$num_psts;                                 // number of pages

        for($i = 1; $i < $pages+1; $i++)                    
        {
            if($i == $currentPage)
            {
                echo "<strong>".$i."</strong> ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<a href=\"?page=". $i ."\">". $i ."</a> ";
            }
        }

    ?>
    </p>
</center>

<div id="footer">
    <?php readfile(__DIR__ . "/mvc/fe/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

footer.php:

```
Made by dn5 | <a href="https://github.com/dn5/cblogphp" target="_blank"><font color="#e1c1aa">cblogphp</font></a>
```

Comment: HTML, please. Better, a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `position: absolute;` Static is default position ;)

Comment: One second I'll update the post with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a sticky [footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) which is always on the bottom of your site?

The CSS goes like this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Comment: Won't the `height: auto !important` always overwrite the `height: 100%`?

Comment: puh, good question. I think it should yes. But you don´t have to change this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a Sticky Footer. Ryan Faits has some clear instructions [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: I appriciate your contribution really, but I'm staying away from snippets. I learn much, much better by coding it on my own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @dn5 I wouldn't really call this solution a snippet. This is fast becoming the industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position to absolute:

```
#footer {
       position: absolute;
       background: #346 repeat scroll 0 0;
       border-top:3px solid #CCCCCC;
       clear: both;
       color:#FFFFFF;
       font-size:x-small;
       line-height:100%;
       margin: 2em 0 0;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       padding:3px 10px 10px;
       bottom: 0;
```

}

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JE5fn/1/

Comment: That ALMOST worked. Here is the output. The pagination is sent bellow the footer. [picture](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/836/1657180315.png)

Answer (score 0):

From CSS tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>


* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```